# Page not scrollable with ng-include="function()" - The code is not in use anymore

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer

### Important Edit

The problem doesn't occur with an `ng-hide` we removed that code for a bootstrap collapse, but it still occurs. My next guess is the following piece of code

```
<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>
```

This is the whole directive:

```
stuffModule.directive('stuffDirective', function ($compile) {
    var oldId = undefined;
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(function (scope) {
                if (oldId !== scope.model.key) {
                    oldId = scope.model.key;
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (scope.model.someswitch) {
                    switch (scope.model.someswitch) {
                        case 'condition1':
                            scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
                                return 'condition1.html';
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'condition2':
                        case 'condition3':
                            scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
                                return 'condition23.html';
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                } else {
                    scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
                        return 'default.html';
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        template: '<div ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>'
    };
});
```

Just a short clarification, it is literally not possible to scroll with the mouse, but you can easily tab through the fields.

PS: It only happens in Internet Explorer 11, that is the version our customer is using. In Firefox I don't have that problem.

### We replaced the code

Because there is an important presentation tomorrow and a missing scrollbar is something like a really big issue, we decided to remove the piece of code and replace it with just normal routing.

Thanks to all commentors :)

### Original question with ng-hide

I have a simple page, where I hide a part with `ng-hide`. When `ng-hide` turns `false` the part gets shown, but randomly the page is not scrollable until I reload the whole page.

If it helps, the data which turn `ng-hide` to `false` come from an AJAX request.

#### EDIT 1 - not relevent anymore

Here is the code which does the HTTP requests

```
this.getCall = function (url) {
    var dfd = $q.defer();
    $rootScope.loading = true;
    $rootScope.loadingError = false;
    $rootScope.progressActive = true;
    $rootScope.loadingClass = "progress-bar-info";
    $http.get('http://localhost/something', {
        cache: true
    }).success(function (data) {
        $rootScope.loadingClass = "progress-bar-success";
        $rootScope.progressActive = false;
        $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.loading = false;
        }, 500);
        dfd.resolve(data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers) {
        $rootScope.loading = false;
        $rootScope.loadingError = true;
        $rootScope.progressActive = false;
        $rootScope.loadingClass = "progress-bar-danger";
        console.error(data);
        dfd.reject(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
    return dfd.promise;
};
```

The properties on `$routescope` are there to show a simple progress bar for every HTTP request.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code? just the ajax request pls

Comment: @AngularLover added some code.

Comment: This is a bit strange , may you have to use the $observe or the $watch. May in IE the digestCycle isnt working fine.

Comment: @AngularLover what do you mean with "may ypu have to use the $observe or the $watch"?

Comment: Can you show the code where you are actually assigning the value to ng-hide?

Comment: @ProxyTech I should have edited the question, The ng-hide isn't in anymore... I update it.

Comment: @Knerd, thank you for the update on the question. I can't see how any of that code would have any relevance to the scrolling issue you detail. I think the only way to resolve this would be to reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) to better understand what is going on.

Comment: @ProxyTech, good luck with that :( This problem is hard to reproduce, it just "happens" sometimes. Also I cannot share the whole code... So it might end hard. I will see later.

Comment: @Knerd, I'm not sure it will help, but it's weird that you are redefining `getTemplateUrl` function based on condition. Just assign the url to a scope-exposed variable, like so: `$scope.templateUrl = "condition23.html"` and use that with `ng-include="templateUrl"` instead of a function. If you must use a function, then keep the function definition the same, but just change the return value.

Comment: @NewDev we tried that, but it didn't work. Nobody knew why...

Comment: @Knerd, try it again. When something weird occurs, a good place to start is to eliminate known weird / hacky solutions as a potential culprit.

Comment: @NewDev, now it is too late anyway. The customer prefers the new solution. But thank you very much for your help, I wished you would have answered this morning (CET)...

Comment: May be a dead question, but I would look very closely at the markup of your templates (condition1.html, condition23.html, default.html).  I wouldn't be surprised if there was a missing tag or character making your HTML technically invalid.  Browsers do funny and unexpected things when presented with these types of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and it didn't had anything to do with `ng-include`. The problem was, we use a bootstrap modal that we open like this:

```
$('#modal').modal('show');
```

But it does not hide properly, the result is that the body keeps the class `modal-open` that causes that the scrolling doesn't work anymore.

Thanks to everybody who helped and invested time.

Answer (score 1):

Many things are weird in your code. `$scope.watch` callback will be executed when the first function will return a result that is different than the last time it was executed. You will certainly not obtain the expected behavior with what you have: instead simply watch for `model.key`

Another problem is the way you redefine `getTemplateUrl`: you should not redefine a function, but change what it returns, as pinted out by @New Dev in a comment.

Fixed directive:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

    // Or simply bind templateUrl in your ng-include
    scope.getTemplateUrl = function() {
      return scope.templateUrl;
    }

    scope.$watch('model.key', function (newValue) {
        if (scope.model.someswitch) {
            switch (scope.model.someswitch) {
                case 'condition1':
                    scope.templateUrl = 'condition1.html';
                    break;
                case 'condition2':
                case 'condition3':
                    scope.templateUrl = 'condition23.html';
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            scope.templateUrl = 'default.html';
        }
    });

}
```

Now your scrolling issue has probably nothing to do with that. If the template is right but the scrolling wrong, you should investigate as to what is causing that specific issue. For us to help, we need a way to reproduce or understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could have to do with your ng-include being empty until your watch triggers. You can try using an ng-if, as this will only include your element in the DOM when the ng-if expression is true.

```
template: '<div ng-if="!whatever you had in your ng-hide" ng-include="getTemplateUrl()"></div>'
```